# Magento 2 : Not getting selected products in edit form

Tags: magento2, adminform, product-grid

Added product grid in custom admin form using :

products_form.xml

```
   <fieldset name="assign_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="assign_products_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Companyname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Productgrid\AssignProducts</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

I have saved the product ids into my db as comma separated values. Now I want those products as selected in edit form.
Please share some ideas.

Comment: Can you share how you saved selected products from grid in database?Because I dont get selected products in my controller

Comment: can you share how  to get this grid to display in the first place?